# What does 'unused loot' mean in the Horde ability in Dungeon Quest

Tags: dungeon-quest

There are different pet types in Dungeon Quest (iOS and Android) and each pet type has a main ability unique to them. For imps, the ability is Horde:

> Picks up normal and unused loot and converts to rarer items.

[image]

I've seen an imp get a normal (white) drop and convert it to a magical (blue) drop. I have yet too see an imp convert a magical item to rare (yellow) or rare to epic (orange).

What does the 'unused loot' mean in the ability?

Answer (score 1):

In the game's option menu you can set a loot threshold. Unused loot is any loot rarity below your set loot threshold.